# Printing smallest and biggest value in struct with pointers

Tags: c

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
          printf("Ingrese datos del predio[%i]\n",i);
          puts("Ingrese direccion");
          scanf("%s",&(pun+i)->direccion);
          puts("Ingrese numero de telefono");
          scanf("%i",&(pun+i)->telefono);
          puts("Ingrese avaluo");
          scanf("%i",&(pun+i)->avaluo);
}
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
         printf("Predio [%i]\nDireccion:\t%s\nTelefono:\t\%i\nAvaluo: \t%i\n",j,(pun+j)->direccion,(pun+j)->telefono,(pun+j)->avaluo);
}
for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
{
    if ((pun+k)->avaluo>max)
    {
        max=(pun+k)->avaluo;
        printf("El mayor avaluo es:\nDireccion:\t%s\nTelefono:\t\%i\nAvaluo: \t%i\n",(pun+k)->direccion,(pun+k)->telefono,max);
    }   
    if ((pun+k)->avaluo<min)
    {
        min=(pun+k)->avaluo;
        printf("El menor avaluo es:\nDireccion:\t%s\nTelefono:\t\%i\nAvaluo: \t%i\n",(pun+k)->direccion,(pun+k)->telefono,min);
    }   
}
```

This is the a portion of my code, i have to print the smallest and biggest "avaluo", but when I execute this code it shows me the first value and the biggest value, but not the smallest one.
I don't know why it isn't executing the "value

Comment: `pun` is an array of structs right? Why not just access it with [] operator? All this foreign language puzzles me. Where is `max` and `min` initialized? Very kind of you translating, but I suggest you to write your code in English. :)

Comment: Please andres, answer at least my second question.

Comment: What values does `(pun+k)->avaluo` take? Positive ones?

Comment: Yes, changed the %i, to %u

Comment: 1) Change `scanf("%i"...` to `scanf("%d"` to avoid scanning octal numbers.  2) Initialize with `min = INT_MAX`, `max = INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the initialization of `min`.

Change

```
int min = 0;
```

to

```
#include <limits.h>
int min = INT_MAX; // or (pun)->avaluo;
```

We also want to initialize `max` to a *little number*, thus

```
int max = INT_MIN;
```

is suggested.

---

We want to initialize `max` to a big value (let's say -infinity theoretically), so that when we compare to the first actual value, the comparison of `value > max` always comes true, because if in the for loop that is supposed to find the biggest value, we would check only one value, this value should be the biggest and not the -infinity.

Same for `min`, but with +infinity. `INT_MAX`, from [limits.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) can play this role (and `INT_MIN` for the -infinity). Check this example:

```
int min = 1000;
int max = -1000;
int array[3], i;

array[0] = 10; // instead of getting input from user
array[1] = 20;
array[2] = 30;

for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  if(array[i] < min) {
    min = array[i];
  }
  if(array[i] > max) {
    max = array[i];
  }
}

// min and max are updated
printf("min = %d and max = %d", min,  max);
```

If you run this example in a piece of paper, you will see how this idea works. Then you should be able to understand why we can use the first value instead of infinity (here, in the example, infinity was supposed to be 1000).

As Chux suggested:

Change:

`scanf("%i"...);`

to

`scanf("%d"...);`

to avoid scanning octal numbers.

Comment: [Error] base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'predio' I get this error. But why is my program printing the first and the max value?

Comment: @andrespm try my edit and report back please. Because of the initialization.

Comment: The console is closing without printing anything

Comment: Show me the `pun` structure. We want to initialize `min` to the `avaluo` of the first item of `pun`!

Comment: struct home *pun;
      int n,max=0;
     int min = (pun+0)->value;
       puts("Input amount of houses");
       scanf("%i",&n);
      pun=(struct house *)malloc(n*sizeof(struct house));

Comment: You need to assign `min` with the first item's value of `pun`, AFTER you have read the data from the user @andrespm.

Comment: It worked! But now the problem is why is it showing me two biggest values, the first value input and the biggest value? Also, can you explain me why you initialize min at that part?

Comment: @andrespm You are printing as soon as you are changing the max value. This change can happen multiple times. Try to print after the loop (store k in some variable).

Comment: Bueno @andrespm, before you accept my answer, I would like you to understand it. I edited.

Comment: like "k=b" and then  "printf("El mayor avaluo es:\nDireccion:\t%s\nTelefono:\t\%u\nAvaluo: \t%u\n",(pun+b)->direccion,(pun+b)->telefono,max);"

Comment: @G.Samaras tha's what I have in the max part, but why is it printing twice?

Comment: @andrespm, because `max` gets updated twice, thus you execute the print twice. This will change if the user inputs something else. You should output `min` and `max`, AFTER the loop that makes the comparisons, just like my small example in my answer (edited).

Comment: Ok, it works now. Thanks, can you explain me this: (pun+j)->direccion, what does it do exactly? the (pun+j) and the ->

Comment: Nice! @andrespm It accesses the j-th element of `pun` and then it accesses `direccion` member of the struct. See my example here: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/structs-c/ . You can always start a new question if you have other questions, because this is already too much for comments. Do not forget to accept the answer you like when you do a question, so that the question appears as answered in the question feed! ;)